# NGINX loadbalancing on Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have some services running in Kubernetes. I need an NGINX in front of them, to redirect traffic according to the URLs, handle SSL encryption and load balancing.

There is a working nginx.conf for that scenario. What I´m missing is the right way to set up the architecture on gcloud.

Is it correct to launch a StatefulSet with nginx and have a Loadbalancing Service expose NGINX? Do I understand it right, that gcloud LB would pass the configured Ports ( f.e. 80 + 443) to my NGINX service, where I can handle the rest and forward the traffic to the backend services?

Comment: do the gcloud loadbalancer offer ssl enryption termination , routing  of urls etc? if yes then u just need to directly register ur service nodeports in glocud loadbalancer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/), a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) will do since nginx is already being fronted by a gcloud TCP load balancer, if for any reason one of your nginx pods is down the gcloud load balancer will not forward traffic to it. Since you already have a gcloud load balancer you will have to use a [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service) type and you will have to point your gcloud load balancer to all the nodes on your K8s cluster on that specific port.

Note that your `nginx.conf` will have to know how to route to all the services internally in your K8s cluster. I recommend you set up an [nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx), which will basically manage the `nginx.conf` for you through an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource and you can also expose it as a [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) Service type.

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between an Ingress controller and a simple nginx pod that is running behind a LoadBalancer?

Comment: The ingress controller manages the nginx config as opposed to you managing the nginx configs.

Comment: Okay, so the request flow is in both cases User --> LB service --> NGINX --> Pods?

Comment: I hope this is related: while playing around I started a nginx VM outside of the kubernetes cluster and assigned an external IP. I was able to delegate the requests to my pods using its internal IP addresses. But this VM is unable to resolve the internal hostnames (the services are setup with ClusterIP: None). I suppose it has something to do with the nginx VM not being a part of the kubernetes cluster?

Comment: Yes. That's correct too, ClusterIP services are not seen outside the cluster. Also DNS is not resolvable too because either coredns or kube-dns resolv within the cluster.

Comment: You will need to add externalIPs to nginx-ingress service (can be internal(!!) IPs of nodes, or can be ip of TCP load-balancer